# Cannot open PDF file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, itext

The library I'm using is iTextsharp but I don't mind any method that can be used to read all text file into one PDF. Thanks for leaving comments and ideas.

I'm using VB.NET to read all text files in a directory and saving them as PDf using iTextsharp. The code shown here can generate PDF, but it cannot open those files. The system tells me the PDF has been destroyed.

[pdf screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMDNE.png)

```
Dim path As String = TextBox2.Text
Dim searchPattern As String = "*.txt"
Dim doc As Document = New Document()
doc.Open()

For Each fileName As String In Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt")
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fileName)
        doc.Add(New Paragraph(sr.ReadToEnd()))
Next

doc.Close()

PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(TextBox2.Text & "\Test.pdf", FileMode.Create))

'Open the Converted PDF File
Process.Start(TextBox2.Text & "\Test.pdf")
MsgBox("Done")
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of adding the complication of using filestreams, you could use `doc.Add(New Paragraph(File.ReadAllText(fileName))`.

Comment: You probably want to do some reading on the system.IO namespace.  There a quite a few methods in there that will assist with constructing file names and paths much more robustly than concatenating strings Path.Combine() for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tie the stream to the document before adding to the document, something like this:

```
Dim srcDir = "C:\temp"
Dim searchPattern = "*.txt"
Dim destFile = Path.Combine(srcDir, "SO72581578.pdf")

Using fs = New FileStream(destFile, FileMode.Create)
    Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 40, 40)

    Using writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fs)
        pdfDoc.Open()

        For Each f In Directory.EnumerateFiles(srcDir, searchPattern)
            pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph(File.ReadAllText(f)))
        Next

        pdfDoc.Close()

    End Using

End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening files all over the place and not closing them. I don't know for sure but that may well be your issue. When you read the files, if you open a `StreamReader` then close it afterwards:

```
For Each fileName As String In Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt")
    Using sr As New StreamReader(fileName)
        doc.Add(New Paragraph(sr.ReadToEnd()))
    End Using
Next
```

Better still, don't create the `StreamReader` yourself:

```
For Each fileName As String In Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt")
    doc.Add(New Paragraph(File.ReadAllText(fileName)))
Next
```

When you write the file, close the `FileStream` that you open afterwards:

```
Using fs As New FileStream(TextBox2.Text & "\Test.pdf", FileMode.Create)
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)
End Using
```

Comment: I simply replace the code but it still has the same problem. Where do you put the doc.open() and doc.close()?

Comment: @Wind, the use of `doc` has nothing to do with my answer. I don't use iText# so I don't know how that works. I addressed a specific issue. You should still do as I have instructed - ALWAYS close/dispose objects that support it when you're done with them and ALWAYS use a `Using` block if you can - but if the problem remains then there's something else at play too. I'll leave this here for a short while, so you can read this comment, then delete the answer as it apparently doesn't address your issue.